# Why does each row of data have the same bottleneck features in the Autoencoder after training?

Tags: pytorch, autoencoders, bottlenecks

I was training an autoencoder for anomaly detection and I wish to extract the bottleneck features of the encoder for K-NN. The model architecture is as such:

```
class Autoencoder(torch.nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
         torch.nn.Linear(curr_col_count, 300),
         torch.nn.ReLU(),
         torch.nn.Linear(300, 150),
         torch.nn.ReLU(),
         torch.nn.Linear(150, 75),
         torch.nn.ReLU(),
         torch.nn.Linear(75, 50),
         # torch.nn.ReLU(),
         # torch.nn.Linear(125, 50)
      )

      self.decoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
         torch.nn.Linear(50, 75),
         torch.nn.ReLU(),
         torch.nn.Linear(75, 150),
         torch.nn.ReLU(),
         torch.nn.Linear(150, 300),
         torch.nn.ReLU(),
         # torch.nn.Linear(500, 1000),
         # torch.nn.ReLU(),
         torch.nn.Linear(300, curr_col_count),
         torch.nn.Tanh()
      )
      
   def forward(self, x):
      encoded = self.encoder(x)
      decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
      return decoded
```

and I am using the Pytorch feature extractor as such:

```
import torchvision as tv
import torchextractor as tx

model = Autoencoder()
model = tx.Extractor(
    model,
    ["encoder.6"]
)
loss_function = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
```

I trained the model with the following code:

```
epochs = 100
training_losses = []


for epoch in range(epochs):
   for row in concur_tensorloader:
      reconstructed, features = model(row)

      loss = loss_function(reconstructed, row)

      optimizer.zero_grad()
      
      # Backpropagation
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
      
   training_losses.append(loss)
```

And extracted the deep features for each data point after training as such:

```
deep_features = []
for i in concur_tensorloader:
    rec, bottleneck_features = model(i)
    deep_features.append(bottleneck_features)
```

Before training the model, I retrieved the bottleneck features for each row of data and every row had different values. However, after training the model for just 1 epoch, I realized that every row had the same values for the bottleneck features. Why is this the case?

Comment: Do you see the same thing after training a few more epochs?

Comment: Yes, i see the same thing with 30 epochs

Comment: Are the two snippets from the same file, so you are training and attempting some analysis of the extracted features in the same run? That should be fine, but you should stil show how you are extracting the features with the lines of code that perform that (currently you only show that you are using `torchextractor`). Also that would appear to be in two places (before and after training with only one of them failing), so please show both

Comment: Well, first one needs to clarify what one means by "bottleneck features". What do you mean by that? I don't see anything in your code that prints or plots any features. Yes, I see `tx.Extractor`, but nothing is being done after that.  Can you provide more info about your data you're training the model with? Dimensions, etc

Comment: Made the necessary edits! Thank you everyone

Comment: I still dont understand what you mean by 'bottleneck features'. Please assume that, for somewhat lesser trivial definitions, nobody knows what exactly you mean. 'Bottleneck features' is not a trivial concept, so please define exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: By bottleneck features, I mean the feature variables at the last layer of the encoder network